# Javascript Timer in 0:0:0.0 format not counting correctly

Tags: javascript, timer

It counts up to 60 seconds, then instead of adding 1 minute, it starts counting in the minute place. The output format is 0:0:0.0    --- the time needs to be accurate and match a program called W-Split.

```
var m=0;
var s=0;
var h=0;

function go(){

    var start = new Date().getTime(),
    elapsed = '0.0';

    window.setInterval(function() {
        var time = new Date().getTime() - start;
        elapsed = Math.floor(time / 100) / 10;

        if (Math.round(elapsed) == elapsed) {
            elapsed += '.0';
        }

        if (elapsed >= 60) {
            elapsed = 0;
            m++;
        }

        if (m >= 60) {
            m = 0;
            h++;
        }

        var totals = h + ":" + m + ":" + elapsed;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = totals;
     }, 100);
 }
```

Comment: for the love of god, format your code better!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from one minute mark, your `elapsed` will be set to something higher than `60` every time, triggering your `m++` on every cycle. You want to calculate minutes from scratch each time (`m = Math.round(elapsed / 60)`), not increment a global. Same with hours. (`elapsed = 0` is then incorrect; change to `elapsed -= m * 60` after you calculate `m`; same with hours.)

Also, note that you want `elapsed > 60`, since minutes should go `0..59`, not `0..60`.

Answer (score 1):

Amadan is correct, but in more detail:

```
function go(){

    var start = new Date().getTime(),
    elapsed = '0.0';

    window.setInterval(function() {
        var time = new Date().getTime() - start;
```

There is no need for *getTime()*, the subraction will force the date to be converted to a time value.

```
        elapsed = Math.floor(time / 100) / 10;

        if (Math.round(elapsed) == elapsed) {
            elapsed += '.0';
        }
```

The intention seems to be to convert *elapsed* to seconds to one decimal place, so all of above can be replaced with:

```
       elapsed = ((new Date() - start) / 1000).toFixed(1);
```

.

```
        if (elapsed >= 60) {
```

You need to test is if elapsed has increased by another minute, so:

```
        if ((elapsed / 60 | 0) > m) {
```

.

```
            elapsed = 0;
            m++;
        }
```

Note that you must now decrement elapsed by the number of minutes represented by *m*. The simplest way is using the mod operator and reapplying the fixed number of places:

```
    elapsed = (elapsed % 60).toFixed(1);
```

which is equivalent to

```
          elapsed = (elapsed - m * 60).toFixed(1);
```

.

```
        if (m >= 60) {
            m = 0;
            h++;
        }

        var totals = h + ":" + m + ":" + elapsed;
```

You probably want to padd the numebers with leading zeros if single digits, so:

```
        function z(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}

        var totals = z(h) + ":" + z(m) + ":" + z(elapsed);
```

or something like that.

```
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = totals;
     }, 100);
 }
```

A simpler version of the function is:

```
function go2(){

    var start = new Date().getTime(),
    elapsed = '0.0';

    window.setInterval(function() {
        function z(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}

        elapsed = ((new Date() - start)/1000).toFixed(1);
        m = (elapsed / 60) % 60 | 0;
        h = elapsed / 3600 | 0;

        var totals = z(h) + ":" + z(m) + ":" + z((elapsed % 60).toFixed(1));
        document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = totals;
     }, 100);
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much Rob, I didnt understand the other answers this worked perfectly!